# Besides weight, what determines how much a vertex group is affected by bones

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups

As you can see, the middle part of the wing, doesn't keep up when I try to pose it. Apparently, the vertices in between are held back for some reason. The same is true for the inner bone, though it is not that much.

[image: Posing]

[image: Vertex group for middle bone selected]

[[image: Posed wing from above[3]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had these vertices assigned to another vertex group as well. Removing that connection solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Beside weight, it's weight relative to others bones. Check all your others vertex groups and remove all weight from wing vertices.