# Mesh not following bones correctly

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I have a problem with weight painting. This is what happens, the mesh follows the bones just partly. I have really tried to paint the mesh thoroughly from all angles. It looks like it's somehow attached to something else and being pulled apart. Thank you! / Alex[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174390/besides-weight-what-determines-how-much-a-vertex-group-is-affected-by-bones/174393#174393